# Fishpig auto login not working Magento 1.9

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

We have used fishpig extension in magento 1.9 
We have worked on staging server like  https://example.net./staging
I am facing auto login error message  in magento:

> Please check this Error message  "error message "WordPress Auto Login Failed: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 09:52:53 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Connection:
>   close Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d55dca8b4d7161c66a76be98b36895aae1430992373; expires=Fri, 06-May-16 09:52:53 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=; HttpOnly Cache-Control: max-age=10 Expires: Thu, 07 May 2015 09:53:03 GMT X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Server: cloudflare-nginx CF-RAY: 1e2c08de44eb094a-DFW"**

Please Suggest me how to remove error message ...

Comment: Please Suggest me how  can  fix it magento

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there seems to be an issue with the auto-login feature when using Cloudflare, as you can see here: http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/auto-login

I had the same problem, you can access the Wordpress admin by navigating to www.yourwebsite.com/wordpress-folder/wp-login.php